# How to retrieve the last part (i.e. a number varies in length) of a text column of which's length varies in Oracle and store this in another column?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sql-update, substr

I am trying to get the last number from a Oracle SQL column called `Description` and store it in another column called  `Thickness`.

[image: Oracle Frames Table]

As you see, the length of the description varies as well as the length of the number at the very end. It is sometimes a double such as 1.5, sometimes an integer like 3. I have tried checking for 'X' at the end but it was not a success since RIGHT keyword is not valid in Oracle.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please don't post data as images; post it as formatted text or, even better, post is as DDL/DML statements we can copy/paste and execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses `regexp_substr()`:

```
update mytable 
set thickness = regexp_substr(description, '\d+(\.\d+)?$')
```

Note that you could very well use a computed column rather than actually storing this derived information:

```
alter table mytable drop column thickness;

alter table mytable
add thickness as (to_number(regexp_substr(description, '\d+(\.\d+)?$')));
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d4a67d4e3406df3350623ab5b03318f)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSTR` with the position as `-1` to start looking from the right of the string:

*(I've included width and height as well as thickness.)*

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET width     = TO_NUMBER(
                  SUBSTR(
                    description,
                    INSTR( description, ' ', -1 ) + 1,
                    INSTR( description, 'X', -1, 2 ) - INSTR( description, ' ', -1 ) - 1
                  )
                ),
    height    = TO_NUMBER(
                  SUBSTR(
                    description,
                    INSTR( description, 'X', -1, 2 ) + 1,
                    INSTR( description, 'X', -1, 1 ) - INSTR( description, 'X', -1, 2 ) - 1
                  )
                ),
    thickness = TO_NUMBER(
                  SUBSTR(
                    description,
                    INSTR( description, 'X', -1 ) + 1
                  )
                );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( description, width, height, thickness ) AS
SELECT 'RAAM NIB 319X319X1.5', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RAAM ZW 327X307X2', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Changes the value to:

> ```
> DESCRIPTION          | WIDTH | HEIGHT | THICKNESS
> :------------------- | ----: | -----: | --------:
> RAAM NIB 319X319X1.5 |   319 |    319 |       1.5
> RAAM ZW 327X307X2    |   327 |    307 |         2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0aeac9625d2dcb71f4cdf5ff5fa7b235)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function containing the pattern `[:alpha:]` as

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description,'[^[:alpha:]]+$') AS thickness
  FROM t
```

I think, no need to store a computable value within a column in terms of data structural design. But if you prefer, a simple `CTAS` statement such as below one would help

```
CREATE TABLE t AS
WITH t(description) AS
(
 SELECT 'RAAM NIB 319X319X1.5'    FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'RAAM ZW 327X307X2'       FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'RAAM ZW 460.5X430.5X2.5' FROM dual 
)
SELECT description, REGEXP_SUBSTR(description,'[^[:alpha:]]+$') AS thickness
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=398c5713b23bbd2c23ee69903f52704c)</kbd>